# Sorting a FormGroup in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting

Aim is to sort the FormGroup contents based on creation date.

This is what I have tried. It is having no effect on the output. Nothing is being sorted. Please point out the fault.

```
sortByCreationDate()
  {
    for( var i = 0; i < (this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.length); i++ )
    {
      for( var j = i ; j < (this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.length); j++ )
      {        
        if( Date.parse( this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.at(i).get('creationDate' ).value)
                        > Date.parse( this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.at(j).get('creationDate' ).value))
        {
          var objFormGroup1 : FormGroup;
          objFormGroup1 = this.objFormBuilder.group(
                            {
                              checkboxesBlogs: new FormArray([])
                            }
                          )

          objFormGroup1.patchValue( this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.at(i) )

          this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.at(i).patchValue( this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.at(j) )
                    
          this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.at(j).patchValue( objFormGroup1 )
        }
        else
          console.log("else")
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please let me know if some other information is required by me.

Comment: You may need to use variable names on the html elements, then grab the elements using ViewChildren. Next, cast ViewChildren to an array. https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren

Comment: @MatthewPitts You may have valuable information. Please write a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup` is a `FormArray` collection of `FormGroup`s. Another way to sort your form array is to get a plain js array of objects of your form values as `this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.value`. Apply sorting on form values and then loop through sorted collection and update each item in form array again.

```
const formValues = this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.value;
formValues.sort(function(a,b){
    return new Date(b.creationDate) - new Date(a.creationDate);
});
for( var i = 0; i < formValues.length ; i++ ){
    this.getCheckboxes_FormGroup.at(i).patchValue(formValues[i])
}
```